# Inner while loop doesn't get executed

Tags: python, while-loop

Found that the control never reaches the inner while loop in this snippet for deleting a duplicate number

```
numbers=[1,6,6,7]
k=len(numbers)
i=0
j=0
while i in range(k-1):
    while j in range(i+1,k):
        if numbers[i] == numbers[j]:
            numbers.remove(numbers[j])
            k-=1
            j-=1
        j += 1
    i += 1
print(numbers)
```

Comment: ah but I found using a for loop will not allow you to edit the value of k.The value of k can only be reassigned using a while loop.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not make `j` start at `i+1`. Instead it starts at zero and never changes. The inner loop never runs because `0` is outside of the range you are testing.

Try this simple change:

```
i=0
while i < k+1:
    j=i+1
    while j < k:
        if numbers[i] == numbers[j]:
            ...
```

The main change is moving the initialization of `j` inside the first `while` loop, so it updates each time you go through it, and never starts out less than or equal to `i`.

The other change I made is much less important. Rather than using `i in range(...)` and `j in range(...)` for the `while` loop conditions, I just did an inequality test. This is exactly the same as what the `range` membership test does under the covers, but avoids unnecessary testing for things that can't happen (like `j` being too small, now). It also makes the loop look a lot less like a `for` loop, which uses `for i in range(...)` syntax a lot (with a different meaning).

Another issue you may run into later, with some sets with multiple sets of duplicates is that your code to remove the `j`th element probably doesn't do what you intend. The call `numbers.remove(numbers[j])` removes the *first* value equal to `numbers[j]` from the list, which is going to be the one at index `i` rather than the one at index `j`. To delete a list item by index, you want to use `del numbers[j]`.

Comment: also i did run into the issues.Using sets was the obvious way out but wanted to venture into this rabbithole.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could remove duplicates from a list in Python by using the `dict.fromkeys()`.

```
numbers=[1,6,6,7]
final_numbers = list(dict.fromkeys(numbers))
print(final_numbers)
```

In this example, we use the `dict.fromkeys()` method to create a dictionary from `numbers` variable. We then use `list()` to convert our data from a dictionary back to a list. Then, on the final line, we print out our revised list.

Another option is to use `set`.
`Sets` are used to store collections of unique items in Python. Unlike `lists`, `sets` cannot store duplicate values.
We can convert our list to a set to remove duplicated items.

```
numbers=[1,6,6,7]
final_numbers = list(set(numbers))
print(final_numbers)
```

Comment: `set` is a much more natural way to remove duplicates than `dict.fromkeys`.

Comment: These are much more efficient thanks.Completely new to coding so wanted to work with the nuances haha.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't reach because `j` and `i` starts at 0 value and in the inner while loop the condition is `j in range(i+1, k)` which means `range(1, 4)` and `0 in range(1, 4)` would be `False`. Anyways, you should avoid using `j` and `i` as counters and use a `for` loop instead.

But the solution is easier and doesn't need to traverse the list, if you wanna remove the duplicate values, you can do as below:

```
numbers = [1, 6, 6, 7]
print(list(set(numbers)))
```

The result is: `[1, 6, 7]`

Comment: Ah so this was why range didn't work. This was actually the title of the question because it bothered me the most.Thanks.